# Why is ansible with a local docker connection so slow?

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm using `ansible` to execute some tasks on a **local docker container**, as such:

```
hosts: name-of-docker-container
connection: docker
tasks:
  - name: setting up ssh_config
    template:
      src: ssh_config.j2
      dest: /home/user/.ssh/ssh_config
      mode: "0600"
      owner: user
      group: user
```

Something as simple as this takes a 2-5 seconds to run. Shouldn't this take less than a second? How can I make ansible run faster? I've tried the `pipelining`, but it doesn't seem to help:

```
ansible-playbook -v -e 'pipelining=True' -i inventories/staging/hosts.yml staging-deploy.yml
```

Comment: Why would DNS and SSH come into picture when working with a **local** docker connection?

Comment: I overlooked the use of the docker connection plugin, just ignore my comment.

Comment: Also interested in this.